# What control should i use to add text to it ?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I could use a TextBox control and make it multiline TextBox and other things.
Or i could use a RichTextBox. Or maybe there are other controls.
What i want is just to show text for reading but to be able also to copy part or the whole text from. Not to paste to it only to read and copy from it.

Inside the click event i want to add the variable content to the control.

```
void lvnf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var firstSelectedItem = lvnf.SelectedItems[0];
            string content = allLoadedMessages[firstSelectedItem.Index].MessagePart.GetBodyAsText();
        }
```

lvnf is a ListView control.

And the variable content is what i want to display in a TextBox or RichTextBox.

Comment: You've already really answered your own question. Use a RichTextBox with ReadOnly set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use a RichTextBox if you are going to have formatting, or anything more than just a simple line of text. You can change fonts, colors etc all in a RichTextBox, while a normal text box can only be one color, one font, etc. You can also insert images into a RichTextBox. It's just like  Word.

If you don't need all of the extra features, a normal text box is fine, but with what you said, it sounds like that's all you actually need.

Comment: I would also suggest to set the ReadOnly property on the textbox, if the user shouldn't be allowed to change the text.